# Selenium clicked button but still getting error and exiting

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, crash

so this is the code i was working on plz tell me where im wrong

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('chrome.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_script_timeout(30)
driver.get('https://uflix.to/mPlayer?movieid=lousy-carter-2024&stream=stream1')

# WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 've-iframe')))
click = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#embed-player > div.main-content > div.play-btn')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(click).click(click).perform()
# sleep(20)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, 've-iframe')))
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[title="Embed Video"] button')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
alert = driver.switch_to.alert.text
print(alert)
```

if u guys are not able to open the devtools goto devtools before playing video and open source tab and search for block-inspection and block its request done now help  me guys plz

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Comment: You also haven't explained anything about what you are trying to accomplish, the error message, what line the error message is on, etc.